# rsync backup to external hard disk exFat fails

Tags: macos, permissions, backup, rsync

I tried to back up data from my macbook to an external hard drive - formatted with **exFat** (bacause of the Windows and Linux/Mac compatibility).

With Automator I will create a little Program, to backup my data easily. It works fine on the local drive and from local drive to an SD-Card. But it do not work from local drive to an external hard drive. What's wrong?

```
SOURCE=/Users/username/Pictures/test
TARGET=/Volumes/Backup/
LOG=~/Documents/AutomatorLogs/BackupSync.log

rsync -aze "ssh" --delete --exclude=".*" "$SOURCE" "$TARGET" > "$LOG"
```

I got this Error:

> rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/Volumes/Backup/test" failed: Permission
>   denied (13)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, I've got it:

> It is related to the **name of the external hard disk**.
>   With the name "Backup" for my external hard drive, it does not work. 
>   If I changed the name to anything else, it works.

(I tested some other exFat formatted external hard drives with other names and it worked. So I changed the name of this external drive to anything else and now it works. Crazy...)

Comment: Please see my answer above. I don't think this works. I ran into the same problem as I describe above.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is older but I just ran into this and I wanted to make sure this info was included. I know the OP is a little different, but I'm using a macbook and ran into the error I describe so I don't know how even with changing the disk name it worked.

rsync can't use -a when the target is an exfat drive. It will make the directories and seem to be backing up but no files are actually created. You need to use:

```
rsync -rltDv [SRC] [DESTINATION]

where:
    -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
    -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
    -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
        --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
        --specials              preserve special files
    -D                          same as --devices --specials
    -t, --times                 preserve times
```

The reason is because rsync doesn't handle permissions on exfat. You will see an rsync error (in syslog or if you control-c out):

```
chgrp [file] failed: Function not implemented (38)
```

Comment: Would be nice to have an explanation of each option  (would edit myself but the queue is full)

Comment: How about "man rsync" from terminal? It has a detailed description.

Comment: We're here. Having to lookup the man pages to understand exactly what half those half a dozen one letter flags are doing is much less helpful than if they are spelled out directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the user that you're running the command as doesn't have permission to make a new directory in the `/Volumes/Backup/` directory.

To solve this, you will probably need to change the permissions on that directory so that your script will be able to write to it and create the new directory it uses to make the backup.

Here are some links about permissions:

http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Here are my [`rsync` to FAT and exFAT instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1785111/425838) that I also use for backing up to exFAT drives:

```bash
SOURCE_PATH="path/to/source/dir"
DESTINATION_PATH="path/to/destination/dir"

# Option 1. **Copy** from source to destination.
#
# dry run
time sudo rsync -hvrltD --modify-window=1 --stats --info=progress2 \
    --dry-run "$SOURCE_PATH/" "$DESTINATION_PATH/"
# actual copy
time sudo rsync -hvrltD --modify-window=1 --stats --info=progress2 \
    "$SOURCE_PATH/" "$DESTINATION_PATH/"

# Option 2. **Mirror** from source to destination. 
# - CAUTION: this deletes files and folders that are on the destination but not
#   the source, thereby making destination dir *exactly match* the source dir.
#
# dry run
time sudo rsync -hvrltD --modify-window=1 --stats --info=progress2 \
    --delete --delete-excluded --dry-run "$SOURCE_PATH/" "$DESTINATION_PATH/"
# actual copy
time sudo rsync -hvrltD --modify-window=1 --stats --info=progress2 \
    --delete --delete-excluded "$SOURCE_PATH/" "$DESTINATION_PATH/"
```

See my answer in the link above for a ton more detail.